# Что означает творческий союз ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Ивановы Ольна и Игорь- творческий союз архитектора и дизайнера. Вопрос - эти люди состоят в браке, или творческий союз подразумевает что-то другое.

Answer (score 1):

«Ивановы» с большой долей вероятности подразумевает, что речь идёт о брачной паре; маловероятно встретить упоминание о двух однофамильцах разных полов (хотя и неплохой рекламный ход). Скорее всего речь идёт о (брачном) союзе двух творческих людей.